# Google Sheets Script Error - Cannot find getActiveSpreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a 'Clear table range' button in Google Sheets for my time sheet so that I can quickly and easily reset it.

The code reads:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet("Corey's Listing Sheet: 2018");
 var sheet = ss.getSheets('Time Sheet')[0];

var range = sheet.getRange("C4:E8");
 range.clearContent();
```

I have no experience in coding and I'm stumped by this error I keep getting. I attached the error and the Google Sheet below

Screenshot of Google Sheet along with the code:
[image: Screenshot of Google Sheet along with the code]

Answer (score 2):

`.getActiveSpreadsheet()` [does not take any arguments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSpreadsheet()). It simply returns the active spreadsheet that the script is running on. No need to specify the name.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets('Time Sheet')[0]; //Consider changing this to below
//var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Time Sheet');

var range = sheet.getRange("C4:E8");
range.clearContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("C4:E8"); 
range.clearContent();
```